# Hiding just some overflow content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Structure:

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentTitle" class="ParentCollapser FancyTitle">title</div>
    <br />
    some text
</div>
```

After the document loads, I have a js script that looks up all elements with "ParentCollapser" and attatches click driven functions to them that allow the user to collapse the parent when clicked (sets height to 0 right now).

The clicking action works great except for some styling issues - .FancyTitle is defined as such:

```css
.FancyTitle{
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-right:-40px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

So basically it reaches outside the parent container by 20px on left/top/right. To hide the content, when collapsed i had to set the `#content overflow:hidden` but that also hides the parts of `#contentTitle` that reach outside and that looks like poo.

Is there any kind of exception that I can define for the title so it wouldn't be hidden no matter what? Other option would be to make structure alterations but I'd like to avoid that if possible since right now its super easy to use.

Comment: Could you add a demo?

Comment: somewhat altered demo to make it work without supporting classes: http://jsfiddle.net/w3xqeae8/

Comment: When hidden you just want the title to be shown?

Comment: yes, that was the idea

Comment: One option I found was in addition to setting the height to 0, I also set the transform scale to 0.001 and the title transform scale to 1000

Answer (score 0):

You could try fiddling with the negation CSS pseudo class `not()` with an appropriate selector. Example:

```css
#content:not(#contentTitle) {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[CSS negation pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Just be mindful of browser compatibility.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be doing anything in this case :/ (tested opera 12, chrome 35)

Answer (score 0):

Since the title should be shown all time there is no idea to hide it's parent. Therefore I added a child with the content in.

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:100px;background:gray">
   <div id="content" style="background:blue">
       <div id="contentTitle" class="ParentCollapser FancyTitle">title</div>
       <div class="contentChild">some text</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now we hide the `contentChild` with js

**JavaScript**

```
this.Collapse = function() {
    this.parent.querySelector("div.contentChild").style.display = "none";
    this.collapsed = true;
};

this.UnCollapse = function() {
    this.parent.querySelector("div.contentChild").style.display = "block";
    this.collapsed = false;
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3xqeae8/7/)**